Is there a way to fake timers in Jest for the alternate setTimeout from 'timers/promises'?
In my program, I use the alternate setTimeout function (returns a promise, does not take callbacks) from timers/promises to avoid recursively calling the standard setTimeout function. I'm doing some testing in Jest and would like to bypass all the waiting for setTimeout. I tried using jest.fakeTimers(), but that had no effect.
I tried mocking the alternate setTimeout function like this:
const mockTimeount = jest.spyOn(timersPromises, 'setTimeout')
mockTimeount.mockImplementation(async () => {})

Unfortunately that did not work as well, and Jest generated the following error:
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: setTimeout
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

Is there another approach I can take?

This worked for me-
jest.mock('timers/promises', () => {
  return {
    setTimeout: jest.fn().mockImplementation(timeout => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);
      return Promise.resolve();
    }),
    clearTimeout: jest.fn(),
  };
});

